# How to run a loop in the statement in C#?

Tags: c#, loops

So i have a let's say 100 statements in C#.

`CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU01_IEmergOpenAct.Force(false);
 CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU02_IEmergOpenAct.Force(false);
 CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU03_IEmergOpenAct.Force(false);`

And so on till DCU100. I want to run a loop in that way that I can access all the statements `DCU01..DCU100`.

EDIT : Everything before `Force.` is a signal container. That's why can't use Array or List (No overload method).

Comment: is there a fixed number of iteration you want to do and what have you tried ?

Comment: Put them in a collection and iterate over the collection.

Comment: That's pretty terrible. Something must have actually generated members with names like `DCU01_IEmergOpenAct`, or otherwise someone (possibly you) is really fond of copy-paste code. Consider fixing that first, because while you can certainly do what you've literally asked with reflection, you equally certainly don't want to continue with the code base as it is.

Comment: Are these properties of an object or what?? This is Quite bad code. make something clear.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ever heard of assembly language ? It works like this.

Comment: Yes, I have certainly heard of assembly language. Lots of different assembly languages, in fact. What does that have to do with C# and the code you posted? What does "access the statements" mean? Is this generated code that you're trying to manipulate somehow, or code you want to replace with a shorter alternative? Its "CCU_O" a namespace name? A class name? What about the rest of the expression before the `.Force` call?

Comment: @JeroenMostert CCU_O  is a namespace rest everything before `Force.` is let's say 'signal container.

Comment: This might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/306158) question. Consider elaborating the details a little more. How do you get the "DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst" monstrosity? Is it part of your code? Why do you have to use DCU01, DCU02 names instead of using a proper collection?

Answer (score 4):

You can use reflection

```
var obj = CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst;
for(int i = 0; i < yourCount; i++){
    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == string.Format("DCU{0}_IEmergOpenAct", i));

    if(prop != null){
        var propValue = (YourObjectType)prop.GetValue(CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst);    
        propValue.Force(False);
    }
}
```

Maybe you need to format the `i` variable to "00" or something in the `string.Format()` call

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'YourObjectType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 2 No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments

Error 3 The name 'False' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Change 'YourObjectType' with your actually Type, I did not put the real type because I cant extract it from your code. It shoul be the type of your DCU01_IEmergOpenAct property. This type is who have the Force() method

Comment: Yes i know, i put Boolean but the same overload error. Seem not be be working.

Comment: It cant be Boolean, since Boolean dont have a Force() method. Put the mouse over the DCU01_IEmergOpenAct property. Look a the type of this property, that is the type you should replace. You can also debug it. Put a break point in to the line `var propValue = (YourObjectType)prop.GetValue(CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst)`, and dont cast it to anything. Look a the type of `propValue` variable

Comment: The value is Boolean I've checked. And `Force()` is a different api signal. 
I am still getting the error No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments

Comment: `prop` variable is a `PropertyInfo`, and `PropertyInfo` class have a `GetValue(Object obj)` method who recieves the instance of the object that you want his property. I have used it a lot of times, I dont know why are you getting that error. Question: It's a compilation error? or an Exception?

Comment: Did you found the problem?

Comment: It's an exception error. And I am still unable to get the solution.

Comment: The problem is that there is no data type.. and hence it's not working.. Maybe it's the limitation with our API.

Answer (score 2):

If `CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU01_IEmergOpenAct` is a type name (instead of a member), then you can try the following approach:

```
IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = 
           Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
                     .Select(i => $"CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU{i:D2}_IEmergOpenAct")
                     .Select(t => Type.GetType(t))
                     .Select(t => t.GetMethod("Force", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static));

foreach (MethodInfo force in methods)
     force.Invoke(null, new object[] { false });
```

Comment: `CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.` is object type. It's not working..

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

Useful if you don't mind writing the whole list once and need it multiple times.

Put it into all individual items into a List/Array and loop over it.

```
var list = new List<IEmergOpenAct>() { // I am guessing a type here
   CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU01_IEmergOpenAct,
   CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU02_IEmergOpenAct,
   CCU_O.MWT.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpn.DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst.DCU03_IEmergOpenAct,
};
foreach (var act in list)
{
   act.Force(false);
}
```

### Option 2

Useful if you don't want to type the whole list but they follow a unique pattern.

Open the Type/Namespace `DRSa09_DrEmrgOpnCst` via Reflection and get all Types that match the "DCU??_IEmergOpenAct" pattern. Put them into a list like in option 1 and loop over them as shown above.

Comment: `BT_CSB_Tools.SignalPoolGenerator.Signals.PdSignal.PdSignal<bool>` does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Not working.

Comment: @mohitgautam05 based on the code in your question it is unclear what the relevance of this comment is.

Comment: The list/array is not working because they type is not available. Maybe it's the limitation of our API.